# evaluation of double order integral using polar co-ordinates

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

When evaluating double integral using polar co-ordinates,
does the order of $dr ~ d\theta$ make any difference?

Suppose,

$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\sin\theta} r^2 dr d\theta$$
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\sin\theta} r^2 d\theta dr$$

Do the above question yield different answers? If the process for solving the above is different can you please explain in general?

Sorry I have no formatting knowledge, so any light here would be helpful for any future questions.

Comment: Remark about formatting: I fixed your integrals, you can `edit` your question to see what I did. Math here is generally written in LaTeX, you can learn it from many resources on the Internet.

Comment: In this case, it makes no sense to try to integrate w.r.t. $\theta$ first because the delimiters on $dr$ depend on $\theta$. While it does not make a strict difference, if you want to integrate w.r.t. $\theta$ first, you're going to have to change $\sin\theta$ into something else.

Comment: If you want to change the order of integration, then the limits of integration have to be changed accordingly. See this [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335845/evaluating-int-01-int-y1-sqrt1x2-dx-dy/335859#335859) for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first integral makes perfect sense; the second one is nonsensical.

I write my integrals with the $d$ first to eliminate any confusion as to what variable goes with what integral:

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} d\theta \: \int_0^{\sin{\theta}} dr \,r^2$$

Evaluate right to left.  Clearly, $r$ depends on $\theta$, and integrate over $\theta$.  If you wish to switch the order of integration, you must, as Mhenni points out, redefine your integration region:

$$\int_0^{1/\sqrt{2}} dr \, r^2 \int_{\arcsin{r}}^{\pi/4} d\theta$$

Comment: Sooner or later, one should rename the integration tag "Ask Ron Gordon".

Comment: @julien: <shakes head> <repeatedly>

Comment: thanks i think i need more work to do in these type of integrations to understand them .

Comment: One other piece of advice: draw a picture.  A picture will make it clear how to define the limits of integration.